# Getting 0 for Long number modulus with

Tags: java, integer, long-integer, modulo

getting 0 when appiling modulus for the return value

```
class Solution {
long ans = 0;
long m = 1000000007L;
long[][][] dp;
public int findPaths(int m, int n, int maxMove, int startRow, int startColumn) {
    dp = new long[m+2][n+2][maxMove+1];
    for(long[][] arr : dp){
        for(long[] a : arr) Arrays.fill(a,-1);
    }
    long solve = bfs(startRow,startColumn,m,n,maxMove);
    return (int)((dp[startRow][startColumn][maxMove])%m);
}

public long  bfs(int x,int y,int m,int n,int moves){
    if(moves<0) return 0;
    if(x==-1||y==-1||x==m||y==n) return 1;
    // if(x>m||y>n||x<0||y<0){
    //     return 1;
    // }
    if(dp[x][y][moves]!=-1) return dp[x][y][moves];
    System.out.println(x+" , "+y+" , "+moves);
    long a = bfs(x+1,y,m,n,moves-1);
    long b = bfs(x,y+1,m,n,moves-1);
    long c = bfs(x-1,y,m,n,moves-1);
    long d = bfs(x,y-1,m,n,moves-1);
    dp[x][y][moves] = (a%m+b%m+c%m+d%m)%m;
    return dp[x][y][moves];
}
```

}

when iam trying for mode with m its comming 0
otherwise its fine when iam not moding with m until the in integer limit reachs I guess

Answer (score 0):

Used `1000000007` instead of declaring it as `int m`, I used it directly beside each number and it worked.